# Dispatcher.BeginInvoke: Cannot convert lambda to System.Delegate

Tags: c#, wpf, lambda, dispatcher, begininvoke

I'm trying to call `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. The signature of the method is this:

```
BeginInvoke(Delegate method, params object[] args)
```

I'm trying to pass it a Lambda instead of having to create a Delegate.

```
_dispatcher.BeginInvoke((sender) => { DoSomething(); }, new object[] { this } );
```

It's giving me a compiler error saying that I

> can't convert the lambda to a System.Delegate.

The signature of the delegate takes an object as a parameter and returns void. My lambda matches this, yet it's not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549358/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-system-delegate)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Since the method takes a [System.Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx), you need to give it a specific type of delegate, declared as such.  This can be done via a cast or a creation of the specified delegate via new DelegateType as follows:

```
_dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
     new Action<MyClass>((sender) => { DoSomething(); }),
     new object[] { this } 
  );
```

Also, as [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) points out, [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824.aspx) takes a params array, so you can just write:

```
_dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
     new Action<MyClass>((sender) => { DoSomething(); }),
     this
  );
```

Or, if DoSomething is a method on this object itself:

```
_dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(this.DoSomething));
```

Comment: But doesn't (x) => { DoSomething(); } match the signature of the delegate? I thought that's all I should have to specify.

Comment: @Micah: System.Delegate doesn't have a signature - it's just "any delegate" at all.  You need to provide it a delegate type with a sig. that matches your usage.

Comment: @Reed But if in place of MyMethod(Action action) (and Action is a delegate) I can call MyMethod(() => { DoSomething(); }); Why can't I do the same thing for BeginInvoke?

Comment: @Micah: There actually *isn't* a signature for the delegate, which is what causes the issue. `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` take a generic `Delegate` object, which can represent a method of any signature. Under normal circumstances (where a delegate is strongly typed to a particular signature), the compiler can infer the specific delegate type. This is why you're able to get away with omitting the delegate type in other scenarios. However, since there *is* no actual delegate type here, the compiler does not have a reasonable basis (or, really, even a *means*) to use to select a delegate type.

Comment: @Micah: Because BeginInvoke isn't declared as BeginInvoke(Action ..), but rather BeginInvoke(System.Delegate, ..)  This allows it to use ANY delegate type, but you must specify it explicitly.

Comment: I'd love to know why they did this! Invoke works in a sane way: Invoke(()=>{}); Why does BeginInvoke force you to do all this? I'll give all DispatcherObjects a comfortable extension method anyways, but still, WHY?

Answer (score 76):

Shorter:

```
_dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => DoSomething()));
```

Comment: Even shorter: I don't think you need the braces {} and semicolon around the expression.

Comment: You don't even need (), so it can be `_dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(DoSomething));`

Comment: Or even _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DoSomething);

Answer (score 10):

Using Inline Lambda...

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>{
  //Write Code Here
}));
```

Answer (score 8):

If you reference System.Windows.Presentation.dll from your project and add `using System.Windows.Threading` then you can access an extension method that allows you to use the lambda syntax.

```
using System.Windows.Threading;

...

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
});
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work. Could you go a little more into detail?

Comment: I've added a simple example. Remember to reference System.Windows.Presentation.dll

Comment: That's exactly what I but now it works...weird. Maybe I did something wrong last time.

Answer (score 5):

We create extension methods for this. E.g.

```
public static void BeginInvoke(this Control control, Action action)
    => control.BeginInvoke(action);
```

Now we can call it from within a form: `this.BeginInvoke(() => { ... })`.