# use lambda expressions as parameter in Dispatcher.Invoke()

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda, expression, dispatcher

I have such problem : 
there is some method

```
private List<int> GetStatusList()
        {
            return (List<int>)GetValue(getSpecifiedDebtStatusesProperty);
        }
```

To invoke it in main thread - I use

```
`delegate List<int> ReturnStatusHandler();` ...

this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new ReturnStatusHandler(GetStatusList));
```

How can I do the same, using lambda expression instead of custom delegate and method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936459/dispatcher-begininvoke-cannot-convert-lambda-to-system-delegate

Answer (score 15):

you can pass this:

```
new Action(GetStatusList)
```

or

```
(Action)(() => { GetStatusList; })
```

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid explicit casting by creating a simple method:

```
void RunInUiThread(Action action)
{
     Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
}
```

Use this as follows:

```
RunInUiThread(() =>
{
     GetStatusList();
});
```

Comment: Hi, i have 2 problems with your sample code. first, last line has a missing ')'. Second if i try your example i get an error, that for the non static field Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Action) a object reference is needed.

Comment: Thanks I have applied correction to the above. Dispatcher is a non-static property on a DispatcherObject, which is the lowest base class of Control, Window, FrameworkElement etc. So you can only use Dispatcher in non-static contexts.