# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate'

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispatcher

Neither of these work:

```
_uiDispatcher.Invoke(() => { });
_uiDispatcher.Invoke(delegate() { });
```

All I want to do is Invoke an inline method on my main UI thread. So I called this on the main thread:

```
_uiDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
```

And now I want to execute some code on that thread from another thread. How do I do it? Am I using the wrong syntax?

Note that this is *not* a WPF application; I've referenced `WindowsBase` so I could get access to the `Dispatcher` class.

Comment: What type is `_uiDispatcher`? Did you use the UI's synchronized object?

Comment: `uiDispatcher` is an instance of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx. I thought that was implicit from `_uiDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`. "The UI" doesn't have a synchronized object AFAIK....but how would I use it? What would do that do for me?

Comment: Ah ...ok, I don't think the thread dispatcher is going to work. Is this a WinForm application?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't providing the exact *type* of delegate you want to invoke. `Dispatcher.Invoke` just takes a `Delegate`. Is it an `Action<T>`? If so, what is `T`? Is it a `MethodInvoker`? `Action`? What?

If your delegate takes no arguments and returns nothing, you can use `Action` or `MethodInvoker`. Try this:

```
_uiDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { }));
```

Comment: I guess I'm used to most methods that accept a delegate provide a signature, so I don't need to specify one. This makes sense though. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this works how I thought it would. The method never seems to get invoked; I'm guessing that WPF usually handles that for you and periodically executes those methods? Perhaps I should just a `Queue<Action>` and manage this myself then...

Answer (score 7):

```
 this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { textBox1.Text = "Test 123"; }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on other answers a little.

`Action` with no parameters:

```
_uiDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    // Do stuff
    textBox1.Text = "Test 123";
}));
```

`Action` with 1 parameter:

```
_uiDispatcher.Invoke(new Action<bool>((flag) =>
{
    if (flag)
    {
        // Do stuff
        textBox1.Text = "Test 123";
    }

}));
```

`Action` with 2 parameters:

```
_uiDispatcher.Invoke(new Action<int, string>((id, value) =>
{
    // Do stuff
    textBox1.Text = $"{value} {id}";
}));
```

*And so on...*

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've missed something, all you've told us is this is *not a WPF application*. I don't think the Dispatcher is the correct class to use.

If this is a WinForm app, your UI thread can be accessed via the [WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.aspx)

Comment: It's not a WinForm app either; I'm using OpenGL. OpenGL uses a GL context, and you can only draw to it from the same thread it was created on. I was trying to come up with a way to run some stuff on the main thread... I've used `Dispatcher` in a WPF app before, so I thought I could use it again to solve this problem.