# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, delegates

I have a base class that has a bool property which looks like this:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
     public bool InProgress { get; protected set; }
}
```

I am inheriting it another class from it and trying to add InProgress as a delegate to the dictionary. But it throws me an error. This is how my Derived class looks like:

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
     Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     dict.Add("InProgress", InProgress => base.InProgress = InProgress);

}
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Exactly as the error message says - you've got a lambda expression and you're trying to convert it to `object`. Which delegate type did you *want* to convert it to, and how did you expect the compiler to know that?

Comment: Why are you trying to add a lambda to a dictionary?

Comment: @DStanley It's not that unusual, is it?

Comment: @Rawling I didn't say it was unusual, I'm just wondering _why_ in case there's a better way to accomplish the real goal.

Comment: I am debugging third party code and refactoring it. This is part of the piece that i needed to get the code working in the first place as it was throwing error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549358/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-system-delegate)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Best would be to have the dictionary strongly typed, but if you assign the lambda to a specific lambda (delegate) first, it should work (because the compiler then knows the delegate format):

```
Action<bool> inp = InProgress => base.InProgress = InProgress;
dict.Add("InProgress", inp);
```

*Or* by casting it directly, same effect

```
dict.Add("InProgress", (Action<bool>)(InProgress => base.InProgress = InProgress));
```

Of course having such a dictionary format as object is discussable, since you'll have to know the delegate format to be able to use it.

Answer (score 21):

I got this error when I was missing

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: This worked for me thanks! Wondering as, in one file this was working and not in another so thought had to be something silly!

Comment: You are awesome! This was it for me ... This is also the first time happening, have been using EF for a while now but never saw this and i expect at least that the suggestion of a Import would arise ...

Answer (score 6):

Although the solution by *@Me.Name* is completely valid by itself, there's an additional trick that may come in handy in some situations (it certainly did for me): if you're converting multiple lambdas using this technique, you can factor the cast as a helper method, along the lines of

```
object myDelegateToObject ( Action<bool> action ) {
    return action; // autocast to `object` superclass, no explicit cast needed
}
```

and then call it by simply

```
dict.Add("InProgress", myDelegateToObject(InProgress => base.InProgress = InProgress));
```

It may save you time later on - if you decide to change to change the signatures, you will have to do so in one place only.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem while writing unit tests. I was attempting to mock the behavior of a database to return a new object from a repository instead of actually connecting to a database.

Make sure your object has a usable constructor. You may not be able to successfully instantiate that object the way you want to. Ensure if you using a lambda to point to a constructor that the constructor can be called in the same way in a normal instantiation statement.

i.e.

```
return x => new FakeObject();
```

say in the case of

```
var fake = new FakeObject();
```

would not work then the lambda will also fail so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this error in nopcommerce you need to add import line `using System.Linq;`