# Cannot convert lambda expression to type "..." because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, lambda

Good day!
I am trying to write an anonymous method using lambda expressions which would return an object from an async task. I would like to do this in the constructor, so that is the reason I can't make its parent method async.

The ReadJsonAsync method returns a `Session` object.
I will show you the relevant code:

```
Session session;
fileService = new FileService();
session = async () =>  { return await fileService.ReadJsonAsync() };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `Session` a delegate type? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like an anonymous method which would return a "Session" object. Sorry I am not really good at this, but I am trying to learn and get better

Comment: That's fine, but then you're storing the result in a `Session` object, which makes no sense. You're trying to store a "method returning Session" into a "Session". You should be storing it into a delegate (which is how you store methods).

Comment: It's unrelated to your problem, but `return await fileService.ReadJsonAsync()` is redundant; you can just return `fileService.ReadJsonAsync()` directly and remove the `async` modifier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549358/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-system-delegate)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want an *Anonymous Method*, you'll have to declare one which returns a `Task<Session>` as it is marked with the `async` modifier, hence must return a `void` (only for async event handlers), `Task` or `Task<T>` :

```
Func<Task<Session>> anonFunction = async () => await fileService.ReadJsonAsync();
```

If all you do is run `ReadJsonAsync`, you may also save yourself the state machine generation like so:

```
Func<Task<Session>> anonFunction = fileService.ReadJsonAsync;
```

Then you can `await` on it higher up the call stack:

```
Func<Task<Session>> anonFunction = fileService.ReadJsonAsync;
await anonFunction();
```

Answer (score 10):

To add to Yuval's useful answer, if you just want to await an inline function, then the magic syntax is:

```
await ((Func<Task>)(async () =>
{
    //async function code
}
))();
```

Note the extra brackets on the end to call the lambda immediately after declaration. Obviously if your function returns a type, then it would be `Func<Task<Whatever>>`

Useful if you're using `Task.WhenAny()` for example to await both an inline function and a timeout task.