# Await new Task<T>( ... ) : Task does not run?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

A continuation of a question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145260/how-can-i-create-new-taskt-async-return-new-t) :

In the aforementioned question I have the following function which returns an object of type Task (for incremental testing purposes) :

```
private static Task<object> GetInstance( ) {
    return new Task<object>( (Func<Task<object>>)(async ( ) => {
        await SimpleMessage.ShowAsync( "TEST" );
        return new object( );
    } ) );
}
```

When I call `await GetInstance( );`, the function is called (and I assume the task is returned since no exception is thrown) but then the task just sits there.

I can only guess I am doing this wrong then.

I do not want this function to return a task that is ***already running*** ( that is ***IMPERATIVE*** ).

How do I asynchronously run the task returned by this function?

Comment: You're `await`ing on `GetInstance`, and that's why your method waits there. It's still an async call, as the thread can be released for that wait. I think you're mixing asynchronous execution with multitasking.

Comment: Unclear what you are looking for, but perhaps [Asynchronous Lazy Initialization](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html)?

Comment: I don't quite understand why this is necessary, if you don't actually want to start getting the instance, why are you calling `GetInstance()` at that point in time? Perhaps you want something like `Func<Task<object>>` or `Lazy<Task<object>>` so you may defer the call to `GetInstance()`.

Comment: I need to hang onto the object without running it because the task needs to be one which can be cancelled. I need to monitor the running state to determine if it should be started, cancelled, restarted, or if I need to yell at the user for being stupid...

Comment: It is expected for asynchronous methods to return a `Task` which will complete at some point in time without being explicitly started. I would maintain `Func` instances to create the tasks as and when required.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**To create a Task already started**

Try creating the task like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<object>((Func<Task<object>>) ...);
```

**To create a Task without starting it**

If you don't want the task started, just use `new Task<object>(...)` as you were using, but then you need to call `Start()` method on that task before awaiting it!

[[Reference]](http://dotnetcodr.com/2014/01/01/5-ways-to-start-a-task-in-net-c/)

**My recommendation**

Just make a method that returns the anonymous function, like this:

```
private static Func<object> GetFunction( ) {
    return (Func<object>)(( ) => {
        SimpleMessage.Show( "TEST" );
        return new object( );
    } );
}
```

Then get it and run it in a new `Task` whenever you need it (Also notice that I removed the `async/await` from the lambda expression, since you are putting it into a Task already):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<object>(GetFunction());
```

One advantage to this is that you can also call it without putting it into a `Task`:

```
GetFunction()();
```

Comment: Wait - Won't that START the task? I need to return the task without it starting, and then start it again. I thought I was pretty specific about that (If it doesn't start the task then it's fine but this looks like it returns a task that's already running to me...)

Comment: Of course, I assumed that was what you wanted because you were awaiting it. Otherwise you should call Task.Start()?

Comment: I modified my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Given the complexity of the situation with which I am dealing this question is out of the scope of consideration (TL;DR : I was doing it wrong). However your answer is the correct approach for creating a task and returning it without starting it.

Answer (score 8):

You should never use the `Task` constructor (or `Task.Start`).

> I do not want this function to return a task that is already running ( that is IMPERATIVE ).

So, you want to return some code that won't execute until you call it? That's a delegate, not a `Task`.

```
private static Func<Task<object>> GetInstance()
{
  return async () =>
  {
    await SimpleMessage.ShowAsync("TEST");
    return new object();
  };
}
```

When you're ready to execute it, call it just like any other delegate. Note that it returns a `Task`, so you can `await` the result:

```
var func = GetInstance();
// Delegate has not started executing yet
var task = func();
// Delegate has started executing
var result = await task;
// Delegate is done
```

Comment: Thank you - but there is more to this than what you think. I need the task because I need it to support task cancellation and restarting. I did not want to bog down the question with what I felt to be details not pertinent to the immediate question.

Comment: @Will: This can work fine with cancellation. What exactly do you mean by "restarting"?

Comment: Why should one never use Task constructor or Start?

Comment: @アレックス: I explain in full on my blog ([constructor](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html) and [`Start`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/02/a-tour-of-task-part-8-starting.html)).

Comment: @StephenCleary : I mean that there is a long-running task in play which executes functions in the background. The task should be one that can be cancelled and started again with relative impunity. Using a Task seemed like the natural choice (given the presence of the CancellationTokenSource class (or whatever it's called I'm too tired to look it up...).

Comment: Saw your edit : I like that. It looks good... Once I get out of the spiders web I'll have to try it...

Comment: @Will: `CancellationToken` works fine with any kind of code. Restarting tasks is not possible; tasks have to be recreated. If you take the `Func<Task>` approach, you can create a replacement task by just calling the delegate again.

Comment: @StephenCleary : I know that. The problem into which I was running (again; a whole lot of stuff going on beyond what I posted) was that if the user acted... well, like a USER, you would end up with multiple tasks running right next to each other. Train wreck.

When I say "Restart" I mean exactly what you say - get a new task and run it...

My solution to the "Train Wreck" is to obtain the task and monitor it. I have to monitor the status when the button responsible for launching (and cancelling) it is pressed because cancelling the task isn't instantaneous. The task runs until it hits CT.Throw

Comment: @StephenCleary (Continued) : 
and as users can just hammer away at the button you could end up with (like I said) a train wreck in which multiple tasks are running towards cancellation at the same time. Rather than just let the user mash the button it has to watch the status of the task. Is it just created? Good : run it. No? Has cancel been called on the cancellation token? No? Fine : Cancel it. Has that happened? Okay : Scream at the user to stop being stupid; once the task has been cancelled (correctly) then the CTS will be disposed of and restored so that the process can start again.

Comment: @Will: Just use a `Lazy<Task>` then, with a `CTS.IsCancellationRequested` check.

Comment: I've already gotten where I need to be (unless what you are suggesting would resolve my *new* problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147144/why-does-new-taskobject-functaskobject-async-work-when-ne ); Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are stuck with a bad design there. I'll try to make something work for you under these constraints.

The only way to delay start tasks is to use the `Task.Start` method. (You also can use `RunSynchronously` but that doesn't really make use of any of the tasks features. At this point the task becomes an unthreaded lazy object.

So use the `Task.Start` method.

`await` does not start tasks. It waits for tasks that already run. Therefore `await new Task(() => { })` always freezes forever.

Another problem here:

```
return new Task<object>( (Func<Task<object>>)(async ( ) => {
    await SimpleMessage.ShowAsync( "TEST" );
    return new object( );
} ) );
```

When you start that task it will complete nearly instantly and `Task.Result` will hold another task - the one returned by the async lambda. I doubt this is what you want. Hard to make this work and I don't know what you need.

This smells like the XY problem. Can you elaborate on what you want to accomplish? It feels like you have given yourself unnecessary constraints.

Comment: I think it would be better taken into chat - No need to transcribe war and peace here... now I just need to figure out how to start a chat session without being prompted to do so...

Comment: *DING* There's been a development...

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97243/await-new-taskt

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147144/why-does-new-taskobject-functaskobject-async-work-when-ne

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've figured this out.  Please examine this code:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Only RUN the task as needed.  FooGet 
        // still allows you to generalize your task.
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            dynamic value = FooGet();

            value.RunSynchronously();

            Console.WriteLine(value.Result.Result.ToString());
        });

        while (true) Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    private static Task<object> FooGet()
    {
        var task = new Task<object>(() => {
            return asyncBar();
        });

        return task;
    }

    private async static Task<object> asyncBar()
    {
        // do work!
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `dynamic` when you know the type?

Comment: For some reason the compiler would not recognize the nested Task<object>.  Using dynamic allowed it to skip the compiler and at run time get to the second task result.

Comment: That's because `FooGet()` is creating and returning a `Task<object>` and not `Task<Task<object>>` (which is what it actually is).