# Why does New Task<object>( (Func<Task<object>>)( async ( ) => { } ) work when new Task<Foo>( ... ) does not?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Why does `new Task<object>( (Func<Task<object>>)( async ( ) => { } )` work when `new Task<Foo>( ... )` does not?

This works:

```
private static Task<object> Works( ) {
    return new Task<object>( ( Func<Task<object>> )( async ( ) => {
        return new object( );
    } ), new CancellationTokenSource( ).Token );
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
private static Task<Foo> Doesnt( ) {
    return new Task<Foo>( (Func<Task<Foo>>)(async ( ) =>{
        return new Foo( );
    } ), new CancellationTokenSource( ).Token );
}
```

Replace *Foo* with anything that is not an object (or any other primitive I'm guessing) and you will see that you get the same error message over the red squigglies : `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Task.Task<Foo>.Task(object, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCreationOptions)' has some invalid arguments`

I even see the overloaded method to which it is referring... and yet why does it think that I am trying to call THAT method when I use `Func<Task<Foo>>` but ***NOT*** when I use `Func<Task<object>>`?????

This works with object (or Object) but FAILS with my class. I even tried it with another class object (Window) and THAT failed.

### EDIT

In response to claims that the first bit does not compile I have been able to compile the following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncFlubbery {
    class Program {

        private static Task<object> Works( ) {
            return new Task<object>( ( Func<Task<object>> )( async ( ) => {
                return new object( );
            } ), new CancellationTokenSource( ).Token );
        }

        static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
            Works( ).Start( );
            Console.WriteLine( "Press Enter To Begin..." );
            Console.ReadLine( );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That. Is. Awesome. Please. Remove. Fluff.

Comment: `Task<object>` requires `Func<object>`. Since `Func<T>` covariant (in .NET Framework 4+) and `Task<object>` is `object` you can use `Func<Task<object>>` instead of `Func<object>`. `Task<Foo>` requires `Func<Foo>` and `Task<Foo>` is not `Foo`, so you are not allowed to use `Func<Task<Foo>>` instead of `Func<Foo>`.

Comment: The code provided in the question doesn't compile - even for the first one which you say does. Can you please make sure you have a [mcve]?

Comment: You can return new Task<Task<Foo>> to make it compile, but I do not know if it does what You need.

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple case of type casting.

It boils down to this code:

```
Func<Task<object>> fto = null;
Func<object> fo = fto; //this is a fine cast

Func<Task<Foo>> ftf = null;
Func<Foo> ff = ftf; //this is **NOT** a fine cast
```

Since `Task<object>` derives from `object` the first cast is OK.

But `Task<Foo>` does **not** derive from `Foo` so the cast is invalid.

So, even though the first code compiles it won't work as expected at run-time. Both bits of code are ultimately faulty.

Comment: @Will - Both bits of code are faulty. The first one isn't unfolding `Task<object>` to `object` - it's just casting. Two different things. You need to recode from scratch. What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: @Will, first step to resolving the issue would be identifying the business/logical problem you're trying to solve, in a new, separate question. As far as *this specific question* goes, Enigmativity's answer is complete.

Comment: ... I have a long running initialization process in which I need to support (robustly) the cancellation of the task responsible for it. Desired Behavior : 
Program retrieves this Task (without starting it) because I need to monitor the status of the task (Created, Canceled, RanToCompletion).

User clicks button : Program checks task status : 
Created ? Task.Start( );
else NOT CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested ? Token.Cancel( )
else : Yell at user.

Task cancellation is not instantaneous; The (and the child methods) have several places where they call Token.ThrowIfCancelation( ) (cont)

Comment: ...Token.ThrowIfCancellation( ).
If the program detects (on button press) that the task is still running (because Task.Status != Created yet Token.IsCancellationRequested) it means that it hasn't yet hit one of the `ThrowIfCancellationRequested( )` calls. This means that it must not take any more action until the Task has reached one of these calls or else we will end up with two trains running on the same track which ends up in a train wreck... The program will retrieve a new task after the cancellation has been completed (as well as refresh the CancellationTokenSource). Hope that clears it.

Comment: @Will - No sorry. You need to ask a new question. Your current one is answered. You need to clearly and concisely ask your new question making sure you detail your problem and include an example of the initialization process running synchronously for clarity.

Comment: @Enigmativity : Fair enough; I hope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148604/how-can-i-properly-monitor-a-long-running-task-which-i-need-to-support-cancellat covers in a sufficiently thorough manner...