# Difference between Task.Run with async await and without it for parallel operation

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, .net-6.0

I want to understand the difference between using Task.Run with async await and without it for parallel operation, awaiting in the end when all operations completed.
Below is the code, I see both operation yields same result as well as same time so both are correct ??

```
// First approach with Task.Run

var themeTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    test = await NewMethod();
});
var themeTask1 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    test1 = await NewMethod1();
});
var themeTask2 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    test2 = await NewMethod2();
});

await Task.WhenAll(themeTask, themeTask1, themeTask2);
//--------------------------------------------------------

// Second approach

var themeTask = NewMethod();

var themeTask1 = NewMethod1();

var themeTask2 = NewMethod2();

await Task.WhenAll(themeTask, themeTask1, themeTask2);

//Common methods

static async Task<string> NewMethod()
{
   await Task.Delay(3000);
    return "testing1";
}

static async Task<string> NewMethod1()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    return "testing2";
}


static async Task<string> NewMethod2()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return "testing3";
}
```

Comment: Somewhat related: [await Task.Run vs await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739403/await-task-run-vs-await).

Answer (score 3):

The first one is not really a thing.  It is just a waste of resources.  You normally use `Task.Run()` to encapsulate a synchronous task so the task manager can assign a thread to run it, so it can be run in parallel with the calling code.  Encapsulating an already-asynchronous task is just wasted effort.

Having said that, `Task.Run()` can be used to run an asynchronous task synchronously if you so needed.  For example, you might be inside a `lock` block.

```cs
Task.Run(myAsyncTask).Wait();
```

In short, don't do the first.

Comment: thanks for answering straight to the point.

Answer (score 1):

In the first approach, the different tasks can execute on different threads in parallel. Even if they don't do anything actually asynchronous, it's possible for their code to all execute at the same time. This can be dangerous if you don't take care to ensure they are thread-safe with respect to one another--for example, if two of them modify the same collection, you can end up with various problems. Also, they must not need to run on a specific thread--if you're using a technology like WPF and try to do anything with the UI controls from those methods, you'll get an exception because only the UI thread is allowed to touch those controls.

In the second approach, the same thread that you start on will execute the first task up to the point where the task does something truly asynchronous, and then it will do the same for the second, and then the third, all serially, up until it gets to the `await`. Then, depending on the task scheduler your application uses and the options provided to `ConfigureAwait` in the code, the *continuations* of those tasks *may* run on separate threads or the original thread. Typically if you're using an application framework like WPF that needs those continuations to run on a particular thread, you won't pass anything to `ConfigureAwait` and the continuation code will be assigned to run on the original (e.g. UI) thread automatically. If you use `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, or if you're using a framework without a synchronization context, [there's still a possibility of thread-safety problems *in the continuations*](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html#beware-implicit-parallelism), so it's still wise to be thoughtful about how your operations may be touching shared resources.

While the first approach *can* see modest performance improvements if the code blocks or is heavily CPU-bound, the difference is typically not noticeable if the called methods are actually and correctly awaiting asynchronous operations like I/O or timed delays. As a general rule, the second approach is the way to go.

Comment: thanks for answering, can we say in the second approach worker threads are assigned internally, and in the first approach explicitly threads are created that will utilize extra memory?

Comment: I don't know if I'd characterize it that way. Task.Run uses a thread pool, so it's not really guaranteed that new threads will get created. In the second approach, there's a good possibility that all of the work will be done on a single thread, and there might not be any "worker threads" at all. There are a lot of caveats and nuances.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach, with `Task.Run`, can be described as *parallel concurrency*. The second approach, without `Task.Run`, can be described as *asynchronous concurrency*. I've adopted both terms from a [Stephen Cleary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75909338/refactoring-explicitly-created-tasks-where-method-calls-now-have-an-async-opera/75909724#75909724).

With the first approach you offload to the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) the initiation of the asynchronous operations, ensuring that the current thread will do practically zero work. This approach is suitable for GUI applications, where keeping the UI responsive is paramount.

With the second approach the asynchronous operations are initiated on the current thread, sequentially. Depending on the implementations of the asynchronous methods, the current thread might have to do non-trivial amount of work, synchronously. This approach is suitable for ASP.NET applications, where over-utilizing the `ThreadPool` is undesirable because it reduces the scalability of the application.

For context, the .NET 6 introduced the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API, that implements the first approach. The `body` delegate is invoked on `ThreadPool` threads (by default), and there is no easy option to invoke it on the current thread. Microsoft [has decided](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/82359#issuecomment-1452168672) that the concept of asynchronous concurrency is not important enough to be implemented in the standard .NET libraries. I have posted more thoughts about this limitation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations/64455549#64455549).