# How is `Task` run only when awaited in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-cosmosdb

How is `Task` run only when awaited in C#?

E.g. in Azure Cosmos SDK there is the [CreateItemAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.createitemasync?view=azure-dotnet) method. According to documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/process-bulk-data-azure-cosmos-db-sql-api/2-create-bulk-operations-sdk):

> We don’t start the tasks yet; we add them to a list to start them later.

> Task<ItemResponse> firstTask = container.CreateItemAsync(firstProduct, firstPartitionKey);

So, somehow the `CreateItemAsync` is implemented to run only when there is a respective `await`.

I checked the [await documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) and did not find any instructions on how to run `Task` only when awaited.

I tried to find source code for the CreateItemAsync, [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Container/Container.cs). But the implementation seems to be omitted and only the `abstract` method is visible on GitHub.

**UPDATE**

As was suggested in comments below I went over to my source code and tested it for different scenarios. Here are my findings:

([`CosmosClientOptions.AllowBulkExecution`] [`await` near the `CreateItemAsync`]) [item gets created]

(`false`, `false`) `false`

(`false`, `true`) `true`

(`true`, `false`) `false`

(`true`, `true`) `true`

So, as you can see irrespectively from what is the value of `AllowBulkExecution`, the `await` is necessary for the operation to happen.

Comment: That documentation is wrong. If the tasks were not started, they would have needed to be started first before calling `Task.WhenAll`. The tasks are started, what they probably meant is that they are not awaited yet. The way you create an unstarted task is with `new Task()` which you [shouldn't do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34145498/11683).

Comment: @GSerg, but they also say that `When we invoke Task.WhenAll, the SDK will kick in to create batches to group our operations by physical partition, then distribute the requests to run concurrently.`. So, somehow the request is run only when `await` happens. Do you happen to know how could I do that?

Comment: @manymanymore Looks like continued misinformation to me. It is very sad, but not uncommon unfortunately, when the person writing technical documentation has very unique understanding of how things they write about actually work.

Comment: Is it possible that the Cosmos SDK is using its own task scheduler?

Comment: See this question: [Enforce an async method to be called once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340177/enforce-an-async-method-to-be-called-once), that presents the `AsyncLazy<T>` concept.

Comment: @GSerg, (or anyone else) if you think you could edit the question to be related to Azure Cosmos DB `CreateItemAsync ` only, please, feel free.

Comment: Did you test it? Did you invoke CreateItem and see if it ever is performed without your await? Just curious..

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The method in question returns the standard `Task<T>` though, not a custom awaitable.

Comment: @IanKemp Wouldn't they need their own C# compiler too? Otherwise surely the synchronous part of the Task will be executed at once.

Comment: I think `CreateItemAsync` implementation is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Container/ContainerCore.Items.cs)

Comment: Check the [`Task.Status`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.status?view=net-8.0) of the task returned by `CreateItemAsync`. I quickly scanned through the code in the Azure Cosmos client repo ([here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/dbdf8064f538c35fc1566554cad68e62eb509d20/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Container/ContainerCore.Items.cs#L65)) and it seems that docs are wrong/used bad wording and nothing out of the ordinary is going there. But I could have missed something

Comment: Tested out one of your scenario's because your findings in the update didn't seem likely to me; the (`false`, `false`). Using no `await` with a `Task.Delay` afterwards to make sure there's time to complete the task I see the document being created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm speculating here based on similar work in other systems; this is not a commentary on Cosmos SDK specifically.

When we're talking about IO work, like talking to an external database, the task *is not a CPU concept*. There is no actual workload to perform locally. Instead, what usually happens is:

- you create a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` or similar to represent the *future* value
- you add some token (including the TCS) to a queue of things that need to be sent
- you `return` the TCS `.Task` value back to the caller

That's it: you're done, from the enqueue step.

Somewhere else, the IO loop is dequeuing things that need to be sent, doing the IO work to send that to the server. Either immediately or on a *second* IO loop, the response will (eventually) be received, mapped back to a the pending incomplete operation token, and the TCS retrieved. Now that we know what happened, `TrySetResult` etc on the TCS is issued.

So: everything the SDK says is *correct*, but: you need to stop thinking of the task as an operation. In this context, it is a "future". There is nothing to execute or schedule locally. It isn't that it only executes when it is `await`ed; nor is it the case that it was started immediately.

Comment: This is exactly why other languages use the term "future" or "promise" to describe their `Task`-equivalent constructs.

Comment: @IanKemp IIRC there was a lot of discussion on exactly that topic, when async/await was being added very shortly after the TPL shipped - whether to add a *second* concept ; perhaps if async/await has shipped before (or at the same time as) the TPL: we'd have different names. But: we are where we are.

Comment: According to [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/process-bulk-data-azure-cosmos-db-sql-api/2-create-bulk-operations-sdk), once I obtained the `Task` I can `await` it or not. And depending on what I chose the background processing, which you suggest I should not care about, will be different. So, `That's it: you're done, from the enqueue step.` does not feel very correct, since after creating the `Task` I still can change the results with my actions, my code. Unless the tutorial has mistake or is wrong.

Comment: `So: everything the SDK says is correct` - I don't see how that could be with them claiming that without `await` the database is not even accessed. In reality the (scheduled) database access may have already completed by the time the next statement of your code is executed. It is very much "the case that it was started immediately", isn't it?

Comment: Here `await` triggers a request execution and that is a confusing part. Without `await` no request happens.

Comment: @manymanymore ok, then that is very weird; that implies a custom awaiter - I'm intrigued!