# Lambda expression instead of Delegate

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I have `Delegate` `a` :

```
    public delegate void doLog( String value , RichTextBox lger ) ;

    public void doLg(String value, RichTextBox lger)
    {
        lger.AppendText(value);
    }

    doLog a = new doLog(doLg);
```

I use this delegate in my `Invoke` call:

```
_textBox.Invoke(a, new Object[] { "aaaa", _textBox });
```

How to make all this simpler with lambda expression?

Comment: I´m not sure what you want to achieve with a lambda. What do you mean by "simpler"?

Answer (score 1):

simplest one liner I can think is this one

```
_textBox.Invoke(new Action(() => { doLog("aaaa", _textBox); }));
```

(it is working because Action is just delegate)

Comment: And why not just `() => Console.WriteLine(false)`?

Comment: because `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Delegate' because it is not a delegate type`

Comment: edited `Console.WriteLine(false)` to `doLog("aaaa", _textBox)` according to OP example

Answer (score 0):

If it makes it anything better, you could use `Action`:

```
Action<string, RichTextBox> a = (value, lger) => { };

_textBox.Invoke(a, new object[] { "aaaa", _textBox });
```

Comment: It does sound like you want to use an action delegate but you haven't provided enough info to show exactly what or why your doing this.

Comment: The question is basically: "How to make all this simpler with lambda expression?" This answer uses a lambda expression through an action to achieve the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

combining the above two answers, I think this is the best compromise:

```
textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { /* your code here */ }), new object[] { "a", "b" });
```

**Edit**; borrowed heavily from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549358/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-system-delegate)

**EDIT 2**; an example with parameters:

```
textBox1.Invoke(new Action<string, RichTextBox>((a, b) => {}), new object[] {"a", new RichTextBox() });
```

Comment: What does your answer add over the answer from Spixy?

Comment: the second parameter and the reference to another question where the compile error that caused this question in the first place is answered. So basically it is more complete and has some background as well.

Comment: It works fine... just ran it in a dummy windows forms project.

Comment: no true, if you want parameters you will need to specify them. Added an example.

Comment: In your first code, you provide a parameterless action *and* parameters. That seems wrong/useless to me.

Comment: You could have pointed that out _in the first place_, that would have been helpful.