# Cannot convert lambda expression to System Delegate

Tags: delegates, lambda, system, expression

I am creating WPF application. However I got error when using lambda epxressions :

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message));
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative)));
```

Please let me know how to solve this. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke: Cannot convert lambda to System.Delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936459/dispatcher-begininvoke-cannot-convert-lambda-to-system-delegate)

Answer (score 0):

Cast your lambda to an Action:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message)));
```