# Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to execute this code on the main thread in the WPF app and getting an error I can't figure out what is wrong:

```cs
private void AddLog(string logItem)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        delegate()
            {
                this.Log.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), logItem));
            });
}
```

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936459/dispatcher-begininvoke-cannot-convert-lambda-to-system-delegate

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Anonymous functions (lambda expressions and anonymous methods) have to be converted to a *specific* delegate type, whereas `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` just takes `Delegate`. There are two options for this...

1. Still use the existing `BeginInvoke` call, but specify the delegate type. There are various approaches here, but I generally extract the anonymous function to a previous statement:

   ```
   Action action = delegate() { 
        this.Log.Add(...);
   };
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
   ```
2. Write an extension method on `Dispatcher` which takes `Action` instead of `Delegate`:

   ```
   public static void BeginInvokeAction(this Dispatcher dispatcher,
                                        Action action) 
   {
       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
   }
   ```

   Then you can call the extension method with the implicit conversion

   ```
   this.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeAction(
           delegate()
           {
               this.Log.Add(...);
           });
   ```

I'd also encourage you to use lambda expressions instead of anonymous methods, in general:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvokeAction(() => this.Log.Add(...));
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` gained an overload in .NET 4.5 which takes an `Action` directly, so you don't need the extension method in that case.

Comment: I had the same problem and then found out that the in the 4.5 version of .NET the Dispatcher class got overloads (for instance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199416(v=vs.110).aspx) that accept an Action delegate, so the code works without explicit delegate type specification.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [MethodInvoker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) for this:

```
private void AddLog(string logItem)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {
                this.Log.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), logItem));
            });
        }
```