# cannot convert anonymous method to type 'delegate'

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a 'BindingListView View' bound to a 'DataGridView' of `Equin.ApplicationFramework`. According to the documents filtering is done as:

```
View.ApplyFilter(
    delegate (SomeViewModel item)
    {
        return item.Code == textBox1.Text;

    }
);
```

I need a filter method that can filter `item.Code == 'SomeText'` regardless of type of items in the `BindingListView` is there any way to achieve this? I've come up with

```
View.ApplyFilter(
    delegate (object item)
    {
        return item.GetType().GetProperty("Code").GetValue(item).ToString() == textBox1.Text;

    }
);
```

Unfortunately it does not work. I get compiler error:

> cannot convert anonymous method to type 'delegate' because it is not a
>   delegate type

I also tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935867/cannot-convert-anonymous-method-to-type-system-delegate-because-it-is-not-a-de) no success.

Comment: use interface ... also how `ApplyFilter` and `View` is defined

Comment: Note that the type of the parameter in your delegate needs to be the same as the generic type parameter you did chose for your `BindingListView<T>`. As such, you trying to use `delegate (object item)` looks kinda wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that method takes a `Predicate<T>`.  Have you tried using predicate syntax?

```
View.ApplyFilter(i => (string)i.GetType().GetProperty("Code").GetValue(i) == "SomeText")
```

Alternately, it would be a better design to have all of the classes implement a common interface and use that to access `Code`.  If there's no way around using reflection, you should at least cache the `PropertyInfo` for each distinct type used as querying type information is pretty slow.